# How to "reassign task" and "request for change" in SharePoint 2013 workflow task?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

In SharePoint 2010 Approval workflow, users can convenient Approve, Reject, Request for Change or Reassign Task, but I don't see that in SharePoint 2013 workflow. The only task outcomes are "Approve" or "Reject".

Do you know any workaround to implement the task outcome in SP 2010 workflow to 2013 version?

Also, where can I find some sample template for SP 2013 approval workflow. I tried to google them but not many results came back.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the name of your approval process, usually beside the Start [Name of Approval process] then it will take you to the view where you can change behavior single task and the behavior of overall task process. Under it, you will see those options.